# TYPO3 4.7 get-started not found

Tags: content-management-system, typo3

Hi I'm starting to use TYPO3 4.7 and I have a problem after the installation:

> The requested URL /public/typo3/get-started/ was not found on this
>   server.

I have actived the mod_rewrite restarted apache and try to enable/disable real url.. the problem is always the same.
I don't know if I have to actvied a page ora a template. I wanto to know why after installation I can0t see the index into my localhost.
Why?
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have some trouble with your .htaccess. Probably you need to change the

```
RewriteBase /public/typo3/
```

To determine, what the problem is, you could check if the request of an specific page works: (sorry, i do not know if there is a page with the id 5. You can see them in the backend or just try some numbers)

```
/public/typo3/index.php?id=5
```

Comment: into my .htaccess there isn't the RewriteBase, I put this line into it  RewriteBase /public/typo3/index.php?id=75 but doens'nt work my browser after point to:/public/typo3/test/ (the name of a page that I have insert)

Comment: when I go to public/typo3/ It point to the Shortcut Target of the Home into the edit mode I think and don't to the RewriteBase I think but doesn't find the page

Comment: And If I write this into my browser work: public/typo3/index.php?id=75

Comment: rewrite base must be `typo3/` (maybe with leading slash `/`) in this case. After disabling realurl, you have to clear the cache to rerender the frontend.

Comment: I have change .htaccess disable realurl clear cache but nothing.. Any change into my index, get-started not found. I have tried into RewriteBase: typo3/index.php?id=75 and public/typo3/index.php?id=75 and other but nothing the same error, I don't understand why

Comment: If I write into the browser: localhost/public/typo3/index.php?id=75, works, but if I click into a link it search a page with the name like: localhost/public/typo3/about-me, I don't know if this can help you to resolve my problem